# ASP MVC DropDownListFor Set Selected Value to Dictionary Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a DropDownListFor in my markup:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.MyDictionary[DictionaryKey],
    Model.MySelectList as SelectList);
```

And my dictionary is a property in my view model:

```
public Dictionary<KeyTypes, string> MyDictionary { get; set; }
```

`MySelectList` is a list of values, 1 through 5.

In my controller, right before I return my view, I set the dictionary value:

```
_MyViewModel.MyDictionary[DictionaryKey] = "3"
```

When the page loads, the selected value is "1", not "3". **However**, if I change the dictionary to a `string` in the view model and the markup, then the dropdown has "3" selected on page load.

How do I bind a dropdown to dictionary value instead of a string?

**UPDATE**

I made a partial view with its own dynamically filled model. My model contains the following properties:

```
public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
public MyEnum EnumValue { get; set; }
public SelectList ValueRange { get; set; }
```

My partial view is typed to this model, and contains the DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.SelectedValue ,
    Model.ValueRange as SelectList)
```

This seems to work for what I need. Coming from webforms, I'm not used to breaking things up quite so much, but this is starting to make a lot more sense. Hope this helps someone else :).

Comment: Since your dropdown can only have one selected value why are you using a dictionary for the selected one.  I would think that the model property should have the type of the selection.

Comment: The dropdown is grabbing the string value from the dictionary to store the selected value. Since this page will have about 50 dropdowns in related areas, it seems cleaner to me to have each one refer to a dictionary than to make 50 individual string properties.

Comment: Fifty dropdowns on a page? All independent of one another? That seems like a bigger problem UX-wise.  But - you could probably use a partial view that takes a smaller model, then construct the model for that view from the dictionary and whatever other data is necessary.  That smaller model would have just the selected property as a simple type rather than the dictionary.

Comment: They're all just dynamic numbers, usually 0-5. I'm really new to MVC so I'll have to look into what you mean, but it sounds like you're saying I'd have to create a property in a model based off a dictionary value? Then I'd essentially have a generic partial view, and I'd call that for all the values in my dictionary, right?

Comment: Probably a collection of models, one per select list each with a selected value for that particular select list (and any other data required - such a the possible values).  Then render the partial (or correct partial if you have different needs for different dropdowns) for each instance of the model type.  Might be a bit tricky to handle on POST - you'll have to make sure the form properties have names that map back to the POST model correctly.

Comment: I'll look into that. However, is that really cleaner or better than setting the selected value to a dictionary value? Is what I'm trying to do like literally impossible?

Comment: I think what the helper method expects there is a property or field but you're referencing an indexed property.  I'd have to look at the source code to see if it works - but given that it doesn't in your example (and your example is simple) I'm guessing that it fails on the property look up.  You could possibly write your own helper but it feels like this ought to be broken into smaller models anyway.